# Edit files on written SD Card (on Ubuntu laptop, edit boot files for Raspberry Pi)

Tags: hdmi, sd-card, raspberrypi

I have just set up my Raspberry Pi and get a `no signal` when it is attached through a HDMI cable. I've seen that this is not uncommon and requires you to enter `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` and `hdmi_safe=1` in the `config.txt`.

However, I am not sure how to access this file. When I try to access the SD drive via the file manager in Ubuntu, I just get the following message:

> Sorry, could not display all the contents of “3AFB-3DC4”:
>   Error when getting information for file '/media/daniel/3AFB-3DC4/ÇÉ╫.#á':
>   Input/output error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ssh pi@(piip)
```

**Remember:** Replace `(piip)` with your Pi's IP address.

*If* prompted about fingerprints type `y` then enter 'raspberry' as the password

You may now edit the file with:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Comment: Replace `(piip)` with the ip number of the pi

Comment: I haven't been able to use the pi yet, how would I have the IP?

When I tried to view the drive via terminal it says "Permission Denied."

Comment: Usually you can just access it with `raspberrypi` on Raspbian (if using a pi 2 it is `pitwo` @DanielMurray Thanks! I forgot to add that :)